# How is the RMS energy of a nucleon in a nucleus of mass number A in its ground state depend on mass number of the nucleus?

Tags: energy, momentum, nuclear-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

So, in my book it's said that the RMS energy of a nucleon in a nucleus of mass number A in its ground state varies as A^(-1/3). Can you please explain how did we arrive at this? Are nucleons relativistic? I'm really confused.

Comment: Why does your title mention both atomic number and mass number? The body mentions only “atomic number $A$”. Also, isn’t $A$ mass number and $Z$ atomic number?

Comment: *in my book* - Please provide information about the source.

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be mass number.

Comment: The nucleons in a nucleus are tightly packed, so $A\sim r^3$ where $r$ is the radius of the nucleus. Thus $A^{-1/3}\sim\frac1r$. I think this may be part of the answer.